# Вызов метода класса через указатель

Tags: c++, g++

Мне нужно хранить указатели на методы класса, а затем вызывать эти методы.

Вот рафинированный пример:

```
class Test
{
    int testmethod(int value)
    {   
        return value;
    }   

    int (Test::*func)(int) = &Test::testmethod;
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    Test* testpointer = &test;
    (testpointer->*func)(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Вроде синтаксис именно такой, какой нагуглил, но компилятор ругается:

```
maip.cpp: В функции «int main()»:
maip.cpp:35:17: ошибка: нет декларации «func» в этой области видимости
  (testpointer->*func)(3);
                 ^
```

Использую gcc 5.3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, чтобы вот так достучаться до члена класса, он должен быть публичным, поэтому добавляем секцию `public`, либо же меняем `class` на `struct`. Во-вторых, т.к. `func` является членом класса, а не свободным объектом, то мы не можем к нему обращаться вне объекта класса, поэтому правильная запись, в данном случае, будет выглядеть так:

```
(testpointer->*test.func)(3);
```

Либо же так:

```
(test.*test.func)(3);
```

Comment: Не отрицая того, что если надо обратиться к члену класса - то да, именно так, у меня вопрос: зачем?! в том плане хотя бы, что зачем в каждом объекте хранить заведомо одинаковые указатели? тогда уж лучше сделать его статическим...

Comment: @Harry, моё дело отвечать на чётко поставленные вопросы, а не продумывать код автора. Не благодарное это дело — когда автор дорастёт, до понимания, того как правильно писать, а как нет, тогда он перестанет писать кривой код. Объяснения в сети, как мне кажется, в одно ухо влетают, а из другого вылетают.

Comment: Ну, как утверждал Шекли, для того, чтобы задать вопрос, надо знать половину ответа... Вот и задается вопрос совсем не о том, о чем надо :) ([Задумчиво почесывая затылок] интересно, задавая вам вопрос "зачем", какой вопрос я должен был задать на самом деле? :)

Comment: @Harry, на мой взгляд, главное тут, чтобы пользователь понял синтаксис, понял почему его код не работает, поиграл с ним. Где он будет в итоге размещать указатель, на мой взгляд, глубоко вторично.

Comment: @ixSci про public я забыл, да, в моём коде эта кухня вся внутри объекта, поэтому видимость есть. А вне объекта я вроде не обращаюсь, ведь в выражении (testpointer->*func) указатель на конкретный объект есть, разве не так? Синтаксис, использованный в моём примере, видел в нескольких местах, например тут https://rsdn.ru/article/cpp/fastdelegate.xml#EGD

Comment: @user206565, Вы не понимаете, у Вас указатель находится в классе, поэтому обращаться к нему можно только через объект класса. `testpointer->*` далее ожидает указатель на функцию член, поэтому, чтобы его получить Вам необходимо обратиться к объект класса и извлечь его. Если Вы поместите указатель на функцию член вне класса(прямо в main) то Ваш код соберётся. На RSDN нет полного листинга, они подразумевают, что указатель на функцию и объекты `SomeClass` находятся в одной области видимости(например, в main).

Comment: Уже потом понял, что сглупил. Проблема у меня, как оказалось, была чуть шире, чем я отразил в своём примере, но вы навели меня на правильное решение в общем. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вынести

```
int (Test::*func)(int) = &Test::testmethod;
```

из класса...

Comment: Но мне нужно будет хранить указатели в векторе внутри объекта этого класса.

Comment: Знаете, что-то мне говорит, что у вас не очень продуманная конструкция. Вы хотите хранить в каждом объекте дополнительный указатель на функцию, одинаковый для всех объектов. ЗАЧЕМ? При вызове `(testpointer->*sest.func)(3);` (обратите внимание - testpointer указывает на один объект, `sest` - **другой**, который нужен просто для указания, из какого конкретно объекта брать указатель на функцию... Зачем это неэффективное в смысле памяти и сложное решение?

Comment: Я постарался убрать из примера всё лишнее, поэтому получилось очень синтетически. В целом задумка в том, чтобы хранить указатели на методы структурах в векторе. Потом, если поля какой-то из них соответствуют условиям, по сохранённому указателю вызывается метод. На мой взгляд это более элегантное решение, чем мохнатый свич или портянка из иф-элзов. Если у вас есть более элегантная альтернатива — с удовольствием услышал бы.

Comment: Честно говоря, не очень понял вашу проблему. Есть вектор структур, если структура устраивает какому-то условию, вызвать ее метод? А смысл в хранении указателей? Или, если вариантов методов много, то все равно ведь проверка будет "мохнатым свичом", только внутри проверки? Но обычно, когда попадается такая, как вы говорите, портянка - сразу на ум приходит наследование и виртуальные функции. Но еще раз - я не очень отчетливо понимаю, что же именно вам надо.